# Windows 8.1 troubleshooting

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics, windows-8.1

I upgraded my laptop from Windows 8 to 8.1. When i try to open some of the applications it gives a message box saying that I need to update my Graphic Drivers. How am I to do that?

Comment: The video card in your computer, did it come already installed or did you install it after you bought your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Well, just install those drivers, find your [GPU(Graphical Processing Unit)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) specifications and search for the appropriate [drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver) to download on the manufacturer's website.

If you have troubles finding your GPU specs, you can search according to your PC model, or try some automatic detection with a program such as [Ma-Config](http://www.ma-config.com/en) which can detect all the drivers that needs to be installed on your PC and provide you download links to get them.

Programs such as [SIW](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/download/SIW,0301-3552.html) can also provide you usefull informations about what's in your PC but won't give you download links for the latest drivers.

Comment: In DirectX diagnostic it says Microsoft Basic Display Driver but i couldn't find any of it's update.

Comment: "Microsoft Basic Display Driver" is a general driver created by microsoft that windows uses by default for unknown to windows graphical components, it's totally inefficient for many tasks and it doesn't correspond to your GPU. As previosuly recommended, you must find your GPU specifications and then find the appropriate driver to download and install.

Comment: @Stakhanov I think this person is just an average home user. That info probably confused them. Have to go basic.

Comment: that's why I tried to but I had to introduce the fact that drivers and devices aren't the same thing, else I would hardly have been able to help him resolving his problem without direct assistance...

Answer (score 0):

Download and install this program [Speccy by Piriform](http://www.piriform.com/speccy/download/standard). When install is complete, run the program. You will get a window like this.

[image]

When done analyzing. You will get a window similar to this. Similar only because my system is different then yours.

[image]

Look in the `Graphics` section. It will list your monitor then your video card.

[image]

Now with this information I know I need to do a [Google](https://www.google.com/) search for "Geforce 550 TI (EVGA) drivers". Make sure you go to the manufacturer site and not a third party site. At the manufacturer site you can search for your video cards model and get an updated driver.